# How to programatically turn off Foxit open in browser settings?

Tags: internet-explorer, pdf, foxit, foxit-reader

I am going to be doing a large-scale rollout of converting from my company using Adobe Reader DC to using Foxit reader. This is largely because Reader DC refuses to open PDF documents in the native program rather than opening them through the IE extension even when the extension is disabled completely. Unfortunately, by default, Foxit has the setting enabled to open PDFs in a browser tab. I found the Foxit settings tree in the registry, but that particular setting is nowhere in there. I can't find the setting anywhere in HKCR either. I am wondering if there is a way to programatically turn this setting off or if there is a registry key that controls this setting that I am not seeing. I need to get this installed all in the same night on around 140 machines (thank god for remote management!) so the less time I spend on each machine, the better.

Particulars:
Using IE11 as the primary browser due to web services we are using
On a domain, so I need the setting to apply to all accounts for every machine

Thank you!

Comment: Important information discovered thanks to @Nick -

install instructions: http://cdn01.foxitsoftware.com/pub/foxit/manual/reader/en_us/FoxitEnterpriseDeploymentAndConfiguration_7.2.pdf

All option values MUST be put in quotes. (VIEW_IN_BROWSER="0")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some research and found the below, Look at the VIEW_IN_BROWSER option, you will need to do some testing to get it but it should get you there.

```
Command-line for installation is:
msiexec /Option <Required Parameter> [Optional Parameter] [PROPERTY=PropertyValue]
For detailed information on msiexec.exe options, required parameters, and optional 
parameters, type msiexec on the command line or visit Microsoft TechNet help center.

Public Properties of the Foxit Reader MSI installation package.

Foxit Reader installation properties supplement the standard MSI public properties
to give administrators greater control over the installation of the application.

For the complete list of standard public properties please refer to: [url]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa370905(VS.85).aspx[/url]

The Foxit Reader properties are:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ADDLOCAL    <list of features>  The value of the ADDLOCAL property is a comma delimited list of features which the installation of Foxit Reader will make available locally. Foxit Reader installer defines the following features:
FX_PDFVIEWER - Foxit PDF Viewer and its components;
FX_FIREFOXPLUGIN - Plugin which is used for opening PDF files in Mozilla Firefox, Opera, Safari, and Chrome browsers. This feature requires FX_PDFVIEWER feature to be installed.
FX_SE - Plugins for Windows Explorer and Windows shell. These extensions allow viewing PDF thumbnails into Windows Explorer, handling preview of PDF files into Windows Vista and Office 2007. This feature requires FX_PDFVIEWER feature to be installed.
INSTALLLOCATION Specifies the folder where products will be installed.

MAKEDEFAULT Default value of "1", Foxit Reader will be set as default application for PDF files.
VIEW_IN_BROWSER Default value of "1", Foxit Reader will be configured to open PDF files inside browsers.
DESKTOP_SHORTCUT    Default value of "1", installer will place shortcut for installed application on Desktop.
STARTMENU_SHORTCUT  Default value of "1", installer will create program menu group for installed application and their components.
LAUNCHCHECKDEFAULT  Default value of "1", Foxit Reader will check if the Reader is the default reader when launching.
SAFEMODE    Default value of "1", Foxit Reader will run in the Safe Reading Mode.
```

[**SOURCE**](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:p4iun6R6OQgJ:forums.foxitsoftware.com/forum/portable-document-format-pdf-tools/foxit-reader/249-control-foxit-reader-preferences-using-group-policy%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=au)

Comment: Glad to hear it, no worries!

Answer (score 1):

Nick's answer, to adjust the installation settings, is best, but if you do need to edit this through the registry, you can try changing the

```
HKCU/SOFTWARE/Foxit Software/Foxit Reader 7.0/Preferences/IeAssociation/bShowInbrowser
```

key from 1 to 0.